Directory setup for PostCSS, Tailwind and Laravel Mix for GitHub Pages
I am trying to figure out the most production-friendly way to set up my directories in a Tailwind and Laravel Mix workflow, and where the index.html should be - namely, I have a src/ and dist/ folder for the dev and production files respectively, however I am not sure whether or not index.html should be at the root of the project, inside of src and copied over to dist, or directly in dist?
I have always put index.html just in the root of the project, but when deploying to GitHub pages, I would have to push my dist/ files so that the stylesheets work correctly - typically I want the dist folder to be included in the .gitignore. Is there a "correct" way to setup a project for the purpose to deploy to GitHub (simple personal projects)

Aside from directory structure: you can't use GitHub Pages when you need a non-static backend, and using Laravel implies that you do.

It is a static backend - I am just using Laravel Mix (not the framework Laravel) to compile my CSS and JS

Ah, okay. Then it's totally up to you how you structure the repo; in the end, you upload an artifact and point the deploy-pages action to it, like in these starter workflows.
